# remote reimage with custom windows 7 image

Tags: windows-7, remote, disk-image

I have a custom image of Windows 7 on a PC that I want to reimage remotely over an owned network, no VPN. I would like to avoid the shipping cost of sending a USB stick or HDD out to have someone on site remotely reimage the computer.

Is there a way that I can initiate this process remotely?

Comment: Nothing in that comment applies to the question. You posted backing up third party software. I'm talking about re-imaging a computer remotely using a custom image not a back up of an existing image. For clarification: I have the ISO and need a supported tool or a protocol that I can use to remotely re-image a computer outside of something like a PXE boot. Currently I'm considering Wyse WDM to do it since the computer is a Wyse client, but wanted to see if there were other ways.